# Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I tried to reinstall one of my old vue projects on my new computer (on Windows 10) with npm but I came across this error :

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...n":"0.8.1","devDepend'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\tmp\empty-npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-09T15_45_53_395Z-debug.log
```

Here's the log file :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose npm-session c13f159e6def7ca1
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall arsag@0.1.0
7 info lifecycle arsag@0.1.0~preinstall: arsag@0.1.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 19ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 5ms
16 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
17 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass 442ms
18 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for node-sass@^4.14.1 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....3.x","optimist":"0.6'
19 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@vue%2fcli-plugin-babel 477ms
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @vue/cli-plugin-babel@^3.12.1 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...rity":"sha512-QysJYer'
21 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@chenfengyuan%2fvue-countdown 502ms
22 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sass-loader 565ms
23 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-eslint 588ms
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for babel-eslint@^10.1.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."dist":{"shasum":"1aa'
25 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-template-compiler 666ms
26 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown/-/vue-countdown-1.1.5.tgz 232ms
27 silly pacote range manifest for @chenfengyuan/vue-countdown@^1.1.5 fetched in 768ms
28 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sass-loader/-/sass-loader-8.0.2.tgz 211ms
29 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-vue 783ms
30 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@vue%2fcli-service 798ms
31 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @vue/cli-service@^4.3.1 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...IRQw==","fileCount":7'
32 silly pacote range manifest for sass-loader@^8.0.2 fetched in 807ms
33 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue-template-compiler@^2.6.11 sha512-KIq15bvQDrcCjpGjrAhx4mUlyyHfdmTaoNfeoATHLAiWB+MU3cx4lOzMwrnUh9cCxy0Lt1T11hAFY6TQgroUAA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-KIq15bvQDrcCjpGjrAhx4mUlyyHfdmTaoNfeoATHLAiWB+MU3cx4lOzMwrnUh9cCxy0Lt1T11hAFY6TQgroUAA== but got sha512-S+Z7k4Qf7p5uC28O3UBfuXq+36cKxzgYPLVx3WndZBNFMEwovCJBRbb2+ibFH+KLh/XqUaY14nJ5zttB39399Q==. (7741 bytes)
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@vue%2fcli-plugin-eslint 825ms
35 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@^4.3.1 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...4zjzPY6pshLSuq9GQNSsQ'
36 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint 827ms
37 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for eslint@^5.16.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^0.1.1","load-perf"'
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-runtime 83ms
39 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for babel-runtime@^6.26.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."core-js":"^0.9.0"},"'
40 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/carousel 138ms
41 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-vue/-/eslint-plugin-vue-5.2.3.tgz 142ms
42 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ckeditor%2fckeditor5-vue 464ms
43 silly pacote range manifest for eslint-plugin-vue@^5.0.0 fetched in 952ms
44 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ckeditor%2fckeditor5-build-classic 566ms
45 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/axios 451ms
46 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for axios@^0.19.2 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ntomjs-prebuilt":"^2.'
47 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/carousel/-/carousel-0.0.3.tgz 109ms
48 silly pacote version manifest for carousel@0.0.3 fetched in 264ms
49 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/-/ckeditor5-vue-1.0.1.tgz 127ms
50 silly pacote range manifest for @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue@^1.0.1 fetched in 604ms
51 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-carousel 156ms
52 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-axios 285ms
53 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cookies 130ms
54 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-masonry 147ms
55 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pdfvuer 401ms
56 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-axios/-/vue-axios-2.1.5.tgz 132ms
57 silly pacote range manifest for vue-axios@^2.1.5 fetched in 433ms
58 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for pdfvuer@^1.6.0 sha512-eyoHt3MPYzcUIssicBbzqSrBe+Vvs6Co9e3kHUSJE4zbr42opQ27LVqMNnPiM9dnMTofeZLJXqqzg2UcJr+4iA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-eyoHt3MPYzcUIssicBbzqSrBe+Vvs6Co9e3kHUSJE4zbr42opQ27LVqMNnPiM9dnMTofeZLJXqqzg2UcJr+4iA== but got sha512-PVC3Y521YB99Okuyfs4L3IH9z3fAyJbsRvktBZMhEEotmhl6sdGd0+j4k4TuI6sUX5dm0iRAJfYdh2/16Wpz/g==. (17083 bytes)
59 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cookies/-/vue-cookies-1.7.3.tgz 188ms
60 silly pacote range manifest for vue-cookies@^1.7.0 fetched in 329ms
61 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-masonry/-/vue-masonry-0.11.8.tgz 198ms
62 silly pacote range manifest for vue-masonry@^0.11.8 fetched in 354ms
63 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-router 276ms
64 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue-router@^3.1.6 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...version":"2.0.0-rc.4"'
65 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sass 750ms
66 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue-carousel@^0.18.0 sha512-a2zxh7QJioDxNMguqcuJ7TPbfgK5bGDaAXIia7NWxPAWsEvNE4ZtHgsGu40L5Aha4uyjmNKXvleB14QAXFoKig== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-a2zxh7QJioDxNMguqcuJ7TPbfgK5bGDaAXIia7NWxPAWsEvNE4ZtHgsGu40L5Aha4uyjmNKXvleB14QAXFoKig== but got sha512-Ut4NN0I90d74RlpsJw+SN6mE9q2K65CQDoDmkp3IIbtE5MPXQ8oXp1+fpXCPNnckvR5Iz9D+TrH2U48xuY2wxQ==. (249091 bytes)
67 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue 1682ms
68 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue@^2.6.11 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...r":"2.53.1","typescri'
69 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vuex@^3.3.0 request to https://registry.npmjs.org/vuex failed, reason: 19412:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
70 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js 1781ms
71 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic@^19.0.0 sha512-yz2M9Q6jMy9zF+JiQiSoaG/m7Eu48H+Yi3FgtVGDFpLDqGUJntNsW26g3qZld5Pa4pgVPRmDcfKHzLTWAo3iRg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-yz2M9Q6jMy9zF+JiQiSoaG/m7Eu48H+Yi3FgtVGDFpLDqGUJntNsW26g3qZld5Pa4pgVPRmDcfKHzLTWAo3iRg== but got sha512-i8dY5Fq7uGzQWnObjTwEfBDFmSPHfwTMDZgYasfuavJSbmGqrG/Ur0fYMnfAAtBDhyPIfmbsCHu2IfWqhAahlg==. (276937 bytes)
72 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/clone-deep 1077ms
73 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-pdf 1624ms
74 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-select 1403ms
75 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-pdf/-/vue-pdf-4.1.0.tgz 166ms
76 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver 242ms
77 silly pacote range manifest for vue-pdf@^4.0.8 fetched in 1819ms
78 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-select/-/vue-select-3.10.7.tgz 139ms
79 silly pacote range manifest for vue-select@^3.10.3 fetched in 1555ms
80 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-utils 683ms
81 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/neo-async 453ms
82 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for neo-async@^2.6.1 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."version":"0.2.0","de'
83 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-6.3.0.tgz 145ms
84 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for clone-deep@^4.0.1 sha512-neHB9xuzh/wk0dIHweyAXv2aPGZIVk3pLMe+/RNzINf17fe0OG96QroktYAUm7SM1PBnzTabaLboqqxDyMU+SQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-neHB9xuzh/wk0dIHweyAXv2aPGZIVk3pLMe+/RNzINf17fe0OG96QroktYAUm7SM1PBnzTabaLboqqxDyMU+SQ== but got sha512-5w/Fy0OUN6Q0yNdMm13G7nu/oMH2zwxyguzA27fy2x0kSDoAm8v/kW7Ca0sjrZAZrHxSrrW8+fZ+wpTpErqlmg==. (654 bytes)
85 silly pacote range manifest for semver@^6.3.0 fetched in 419ms
86 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-sweetalert2 1686ms
87 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/domready 147ms
88 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-eslint-parser 170ms
89 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue-eslint-parser@^5.0.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ollup-plugin-sourcema'
90 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-utils/-/loader-utils-1.4.0.tgz 125ms
91 silly pacote range manifest for loader-utils@^1.2.3 fetched in 821ms
92 silly pacote range manifest for loader-utils@^1.4.0 fetched in 4ms
93 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/schema-utils 580ms
94 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for schema-utils@^2.6.1 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...8f0a7e624263073d396e2'
95 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/masonry-layout 99ms
96 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for core-js@^2.6.11 sha512-5wjnpaT/3dV+XB4borEsnAYQchn00XSgTAWKDkEqv+K8KevjbzmofK6hfJ9TZIlpj2N0xQpazy7PiRQiWHqzWg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-5wjnpaT/3dV+XB4borEsnAYQchn00XSgTAWKDkEqv+K8KevjbzmofK6hfJ9TZIlpj2N0xQpazy7PiRQiWHqzWg== but got sha512-ZNPvpgsu5hidcaNp5lHeblqtIIirHztf3ZiyxFg+RMjJ/lxoMW+iP4NFFpTqWMbhkeWbpmLEEt7AjGZRGVdhSw==. (383436 bytes)
97 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue 171ms (from cache)
98 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue@^2.0.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...r":"2.53.1","typescri'
99 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/domready/-/domready-0.2.13.tgz 230ms
100 silly pacote range manifest for domready@~0.2.12 fetched in 390ms
101 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/masonry-layout/-/masonry-layout-4.2.2.tgz 243ms
102 silly pacote range manifest for masonry-layout@^4.2.2 fetched in 355ms
103 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/imagesloaded 513ms
104 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/big.js 190ms
105 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pdfjs-dist 370ms
106 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for pdfjs-dist@^2.5.207 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...js-dist","version":"1'
107 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/emojis-list 171ms
108 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import 508ms
109 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for sass@^1.26.5 sha512-bzN0uvmzfsTvjz0qwccN1sPm2HxxpNI/Xa+7PlUEMS+nQvbyuEK7Y0qFqxlPHhiNHb1Ze8WQJtU31olMObkAMw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-bzN0uvmzfsTvjz0qwccN1sPm2HxxpNI/Xa+7PlUEMS+nQvbyuEK7Y0qFqxlPHhiNHb1Ze8WQJtU31olMObkAMw== but got sha512-C0orBxJ8KarR2TGuAvwOZoKojYzWEDjil00+Y0GbNSVUFWycrW6bXGUlD5Vzm7Epv0CeVI4m5a0l+ekMYIdlTQ==. (375242 bytes)
110 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-loader 531ms
111 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/worker-loader 529ms
112 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for worker-loader@^2.0.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...endencies":{"schema-u'
113 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/big.js/-/big.js-5.2.2.tgz 202ms
114 silly pacote range manifest for big.js@^5.2.2 fetched in 400ms
115 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/emojis-list/-/emojis-list-3.0.0.tgz 152ms
116 silly pacote range manifest for emojis-list@^3.0.0 fetched in 333ms
117 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/json5 183ms
118 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-resize-sensor 523ms
119 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-loader/-/raw-loader-4.0.1.tgz 139ms
120 silly pacote range manifest for raw-loader@^4.0.1 fetched in 683ms
121 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-resize-sensor/-/vue-resize-sensor-2.0.0.tgz 90ms
122 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/json5/-/json5-1.0.1.tgz 94ms
123 silly pacote range manifest for vue-resize-sensor@^2.0.0 fetched in 650ms
124 silly pacote range manifest for json5@^1.0.1 fetched in 314ms
125 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/schema-utils 110ms (from cache)
126 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for schema-utils@^2.6.5 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...8f0a7e624263073d396e2'
127 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-utils/-/loader-utils-2.0.0.tgz 115ms
128 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/-/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import-6.18.0.tgz 323ms
129 silly pacote range manifest for loader-utils@^2.0.0 fetched in 130ms
130 silly pacote range manifest for babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@^6.18.0 fetched in 857ms
131 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/get-size 328ms
132 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-sweetalert2/-/vue-sweetalert2-2.1.5.tgz 872ms
133 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/outlayer 293ms
134 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/imagesloaded/-/imagesloaded-4.1.4.tgz 455ms
135 silly pacote range manifest for vue-sweetalert2@^2.1.5 fetched in 2579ms
136 silly pacote version manifest for imagesloaded@4.1.4 fetched in 983ms
137 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist 89ms
138 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for minimist@^1.2.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...e":"-----BEGIN PGP SI'
139 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for get-size@^2.0.2 request to https://registry.npmjs.org/get-size/-/get-size-2.0.3.tgz failed, reason: 19412:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
140 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for outlayer@^2.1.0 request to https://registry.npmjs.org/outlayer/-/outlayer-2.1.1.tgz failed, reason: 19412:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
141 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ev-emitter 107ms
142 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/json5/-/json5-2.1.3.tgz 170ms
143 silly pacote range manifest for json5@^2.1.2 fetched in 179ms
144 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ev-emitter/-/ev-emitter-1.1.1.tgz 79ms
145 silly pacote range manifest for ev-emitter@^1.0.0 fetched in 196ms
146 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist 71ms (from cache)
147 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for minimist@^1.2.5 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...e":"-----BEGIN PGP SI'
148 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sweetalert2 248ms
149 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for sweetalert2@8.x Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^2.5.3","uglify-js"'
150 silly pacote range manifest for @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue@^1.0.1 fetched in 17ms
151 silly resolveWithNewModule @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue@1.0.1 checking installable status
152 silly pacote range manifest for @chenfengyuan/vue-countdown@^1.1.5 fetched in 23ms
153 silly resolveWithNewModule @chenfengyuan/vue-countdown@1.1.5 checking installable status
154 silly pacote version manifest for carousel@0.0.3 fetched in 22ms
155 silly resolveWithNewModule carousel@0.0.3 checking installable status
156 silly pacote range manifest for vue-cookies@^1.7.0 fetched in 9ms
157 silly resolveWithNewModule vue-cookies@1.7.3 checking installable status
158 silly pacote range manifest for vue-axios@^2.1.5 fetched in 19ms
159 silly resolveWithNewModule vue-axios@2.1.5 checking installable status
160 silly pacote range manifest for vue-masonry@^0.11.8 fetched in 5ms
161 silly resolveWithNewModule vue-masonry@0.11.8 checking installable status
162 silly pacote range manifest for vue-pdf@^4.0.8 fetched in 8ms
163 silly resolveWithNewModule vue-pdf@4.1.0 checking installable status
164 silly pacote range manifest for vue-select@^3.10.3 fetched in 2ms
165 silly resolveWithNewModule vue-select@3.10.7 checking installable status
166 silly pacote range manifest for vue-sweetalert2@^2.1.5 fetched in 4ms
167 silly resolveWithNewModule vue-sweetalert2@2.1.5 checking installable status
168 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/axios 108ms (from cache)
169 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for axios@^0.19.2 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ntomjs-prebuilt":"^2.'
170 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for sass@^1.26.5 sha512-bzN0uvmzfsTvjz0qwccN1sPm2HxxpNI/Xa+7PlUEMS+nQvbyuEK7Y0qFqxlPHhiNHb1Ze8WQJtU31olMObkAMw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-bzN0uvmzfsTvjz0qwccN1sPm2HxxpNI/Xa+7PlUEMS+nQvbyuEK7Y0qFqxlPHhiNHb1Ze8WQJtU31olMObkAMw== but got sha512-boKHQgmSvlyiDBKcVedXAItDt0vaoluv+WblsBSh+LGME1o35TcAUEd7n6XPsydPpmyOghITdmc7gUVNPtXONw==. (64750 bytes)
171 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic@^19.0.0 sha512-yz2M9Q6jMy9zF+JiQiSoaG/m7Eu48H+Yi3FgtVGDFpLDqGUJntNsW26g3qZld5Pa4pgVPRmDcfKHzLTWAo3iRg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-yz2M9Q6jMy9zF+JiQiSoaG/m7Eu48H+Yi3FgtVGDFpLDqGUJntNsW26g3qZld5Pa4pgVPRmDcfKHzLTWAo3iRg== but got sha512-W1KOMtFwMspyKzkIw3E50by2qavhexBdSsGK0o7e1X81kaWU6dWcxEuPenIZxBVRB0cE43oTrfkOzql9Y8Wgbw==. (24650 bytes)
172 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue 194ms (from cache)
173 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue@^2.6.11 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...r":"2.53.1","typescri'
174 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-runtime 205ms (from cache)
175 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for babel-runtime@^6.26.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."core-js":"^0.9.0"},"'
176 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for core-js@^2.6.11 sha512-5wjnpaT/3dV+XB4borEsnAYQchn00XSgTAWKDkEqv+K8KevjbzmofK6hfJ9TZIlpj2N0xQpazy7PiRQiWHqzWg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-5wjnpaT/3dV+XB4borEsnAYQchn00XSgTAWKDkEqv+K8KevjbzmofK6hfJ9TZIlpj2N0xQpazy7PiRQiWHqzWg== but got sha512-jjYgidcMViTqtJUFr2W6iXzoYDXy0nekCHvVTPYCKvdXWFBO2Xtg3/ClXtW7eLQ//QUevpF8Jj5cFPsrtG0tpw==. (101747 bytes)
177 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-router 312ms (from cache)
178 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue-router@^3.1.6 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...version":"2.0.0-rc.4"'
179 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vuex 412ms
180 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for pdfvuer@^1.6.0 sha512-eyoHt3MPYzcUIssicBbzqSrBe+Vvs6Co9e3kHUSJE4zbr42opQ27LVqMNnPiM9dnMTofeZLJXqqzg2UcJr+4iA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-eyoHt3MPYzcUIssicBbzqSrBe+Vvs6Co9e3kHUSJE4zbr42opQ27LVqMNnPiM9dnMTofeZLJXqqzg2UcJr+4iA== but got sha512-eVmayzvKMe23+F29ESoN4H4iBw65sX+cpVQ4ZtYyeFdeSzImtkhQBrJTWoR+6yIfkNhIZIlSB33x4fMhZyPA/A==. (171515 bytes)
181 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vuex@^3.3.0 sha512-w7oJzmHQs0FM9LXodfskhw9wgKBiaB+totOdb8sNzbTB2KDCEEwEs29NzBZFh/lmEK1t5tDmM1vtsO7ubG1DFw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-w7oJzmHQs0FM9LXodfskhw9wgKBiaB+totOdb8sNzbTB2KDCEEwEs29NzBZFh/lmEK1t5tDmM1vtsO7ubG1DFw== but got sha512-tykHtbDV9xkOHL+t5TE3aM8m6Mba7FMmIxpprwW/wifzQHwCcfAn/y+5TlT0lSlak6RbiTSeQnkxAxZn4W5cSQ==. (2022 bytes)
182 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for vue-carousel@^0.18.0 sha512-a2zxh7QJioDxNMguqcuJ7TPbfgK5bGDaAXIia7NWxPAWsEvNE4ZtHgsGu40L5Aha4uyjmNKXvleB14QAXFoKig== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-a2zxh7QJioDxNMguqcuJ7TPbfgK5bGDaAXIia7NWxPAWsEvNE4ZtHgsGu40L5Aha4uyjmNKXvleB14QAXFoKig== but got sha512-6b5wIdas1Xqd9vsQtcwDKF7WzJ6aAMEN6fzH0NZvSBFcz92J42drpPWrncgGfqJN6jGMiwqGdUH72wst9IJV2Q==. (326894 bytes)
183 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
184 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 4978ms
185 silly saveTree arsag@0.1.0
185 silly saveTree +-- @chenfengyuan/vue-countdown@1.1.5
185 silly saveTree +-- @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue@1.0.1
185 silly saveTree +-- carousel@0.0.3
185 silly saveTree +-- vue-axios@2.1.5
185 silly saveTree +-- vue-cookies@1.7.3
185 silly saveTree +-- vue-masonry@0.11.8
185 silly saveTree +-- vue-pdf@4.1.0
185 silly saveTree +-- vue-select@3.10.7
185 silly saveTree `-- vue-sweetalert2@2.1.5
186 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ntomjs-prebuilt":"^2.'
186 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
186 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
186 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
186 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
186 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
187 verbose cwd C:\wamp64\www\arsag
188 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
189 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
190 verbose node v12.18.3
191 verbose npm  v6.14.6
192 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ntomjs-prebuilt":"^2.'
193 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've tried to delete node_packages, `npm cache clean --force`and then `npm install` but without the expected result.

I've also tried with the NodeJS cmd prompt for windows and with the Ubuntu subshell

Comment: seems that you got some internet connection problem and it can't fetch the full json files, are you using some proxy or vpn?

Comment: I'm using my phone to access the Internet. May it be the cause of my troubles ?

Comment: Just tried to change my internet connection and it works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you still see the error even after connecting to a "real/stable" wi-fi, try,

1. increase timeout for package fetch retry

> npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 60000 -g

2. Clean cache -

> npm cache clean --force

3. run install again,

> npm install

Alternatively, it could be a case where the error could be due to a locked package version in package.json, for such cases execute the following steps,

1. delete **package.lock.json**
2. run **npm install**

Answer (score 4):

Just to bring to sight the answer given by Flash Thunder, the problem was my internet connection. I was using my phone to access the Internet. After connecting my computer to the closest wifi, everything is working fine

Comment: Same here. I happened to have an wi-fi extender in the basement where I work. As soon I went back upstairs and connected to the "real" wi-fi, it started working. Is there a way to configure npm's timeout?

Comment: I guess I found the answer: npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 60000 -g?